# Medical Marijuana

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answering-questions

I read a couple of posts about the legality and so on related to growing marijuana but I don't think they were specific to the fact that in many states, including California, consumption and even growing it is not illegal as long as it fits within the limitations set by the law governing it.

Patients are allowed to obtain it for medical use from dispensaries or co-ops and even are limited to having two mature plants and up to 4 new plants for a total of 6 total (which actually have red label stickers on them identifying them as medically permitted plants).

However, not everyone who is a patient who needs it or has the legal permission to grow it know how to do it, everything from germination, planting, lighting, pruning, and ultimately harvesting. So would questions regarding manners to help such people become self sufficient in this matter be allowed? Even the federal government has acknowledged that the DEA will no longer go after people/dispensaries inside states where medical use of marijuana is legalized.

SO if a patient who wants to do this asks for help with seeds, growing tips and so on, is that allowed? Also, obviously people replying are not all patients but may have expertise to help them, is that also allowed? I personally think it should be allowed as we are not police and what people do with information provided is their responsibility and legal liability, not ours. As an attorney I also highly disagree with the statement that government can ask for the users' information and we are required to provide it to them.

Comment: While not strictly a duplicate, this is answered on the linked post. Questions on sourcing probably aren't OK as questions on sourcing in general aren't good fits for SE. Questions about cultivation are fine.

Comment: This is in no way about illegal activity and for you to mark it as duplicate of illegal activity is offensive. Its also not about sourcing but rather helping people with legal right to grow for themselves to get help doing so. I believe this marking is inaccurate.

Comment: To be clear. It's illegal in some places and not in another. Indignation that it's classified with a question about other *sometimes* illegal activity isn't helpful to the dialogue here. Fact: growing marijuana for *any* purpose is still illegal under federal law. Fact: growing marijuana for *any* purpose is still illegal in New York where SEI is located. That makes this question identical to the question asked. I've asked another mod to take a look at my decision here, but I'm not seeing the issue.

Comment: I have to agree with @waxeagle: growing marijuana is illegal in a lot of places. You may not be breaking California law by growing 6 red-tagged plants, but you certainly would be if you grew 60,000 in the Mendocino National Forest. Answers to the duplicate offer a reasonable policy which allows for questions about their cultivation.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-questions-about-a-marijuana-garden-allowed

Comment: 20 states in which it is either legal for medical use or outright legal for personal use and we are splitting hair about NY? We are not suggesting people should break the law where its illegal, but help those where it IS legal. Just about any subject can have the implication of being illegal somewhere, doesn't mean it should't be discussed? Even the federal government has suspended messing with states where there is legal statutes on the books, so as long as you are not promoting illegal activity, answering questions to a legal matter is hardly a violation of anything. This seems wrong.

Comment: Did you read the top answer to the duplicate? It argues *for* allowing these questions. And we agree. There's not argument that they are allowed.

Comment: Yes I did and I agree with Daniel Bingham's answer and believe its the most enlightened one I have heard so far. But to link my question to one being labeled illegal activity is inappropriate. I am not advocating illegal activity, never have, but rather the legal and supportive mechanism by which we can support the greater good without letting the potentiality of illegal activity by a minority to overshadow it. The asker wants to know how to respond to illegal activity, I am specifically asking about LEGAL activity, see? not duplicate.